# Can not remove \u200B zero space in text with javascript

Tags: javascript, replace, zero-width-space

I am not able to remove zero width character from a string. It is no problem to remove any other character, only the '\u200B' seems to resist my tries.

I am getting strings from my API that contain zero spaces (\u200B) that are used to tell the mobile app where to break words. Now within a comparison in my web app I need to get rid of these zero spaces.

I tried

```
ingredient = ingredient.replace(/\u200B/g,'')
```

with a large 'B' and a small 'b' and the same with lodash

```
_.replace(ingredient, '\u200B', '');
```

but none of my options seem to work. Any ideas?

Comment: Using string replace (your first code sample) worked for me. How are you checking the result?

Comment: It was an error from the server. Some of the items had '\u200B' and some had '\\u200B'. Both are invisible and seem to be the same. I found the problem by comparing the strings and then their length.